# replaceall REGEX in java

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

Completely new to java and I have been playing around with regex in a replaceAll command and wondered if the way that I have done it is the best way?
I basically wanted to find every occurence of 
`<Letter_File TIMESTAMP="0000-00-00 00:00" FILECREATOR="XXX" BRAND_ID="0" BRAND_NAME="xxxxxxxxx">`
within my file and replace it with `<Letter_File>` i am using the following:

`str1 = str1.replaceAll("\\<Letter\\_File[a-zA-Z\\_\\s\\=\\\"0-9-\\:\\\"]+\\>","<Letter_File>");>`

what I wanted to know, is this the best way of doing the function or is there a way that the REGEX can be shortened?

Any feedback is more then welcome.

Thanks

Comment: so basically you are trying to replace the tag <Letter_File TIMESTAMP="0000-00-00 00:00" FILECREATOR="XXX" BRAND_ID="0" BRAND_NAME="xxxxxxxxx"> with <Letter_File> tag in your XML file right ?

Comment: yes correct I basically want to strip all of the attributes out of the <Letter_File> tag, I know that this is probably a very noobish way of doing so!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
str1 = str1.replaceAll("<Letter_File[^>]+>","<Letter_File>");>
```

Comment: Thanks this works fine, just out of curiousity could you explain how this works? am I right in assuming that the [^>] will look for anything after the <Letter_File upto the >? I thought that you had to put in the certain characters it looked for hence why I put all of those different variations e.g. a-zA-Z0-9 etc. etc.

Comment: @Simon.Knott86: `[^>]` means any character that is not `>`. Have a look at this site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: thanks very much I think that helps alot, I wasnt sure as the ^ character to my understanding can also mean "at the start of"

Comment: @Simon.Knott86: Yes the `^` means start of string except when inside a character class it negates the class.